# Negative current sense limit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I would like to find the expression of voltage across **Rsense** in the circuit below:
[image]

The author says in the book:
"A multiplier generates a current which is a product of the rectified line voltage **k.Vin(t)** and the error amplifier output level **Verr**". This current generator feeds an **offset resistor Rcs** connected to the sense element **Rsense* in series with DC low side input terminal. **Rcs fixes the maximum peak inductor current allowed by the multiplier. For instance, suppose the the multiplier delivers 300 uA and Rcs equals 2 kohm; then the maximum voltage across Rsense reaches **600 mV****

(the inductor is just above the transistor connected in a boost configuration with a diode)

1. What bothered me in this circuit is the last statement, i.e How does the resistor **Rcs** fixes the maximum peak inductor current current?
2. What is the mathematical expression of Vsense in terms of the current entering Rcs and the inductor current entering Rsense from low side?

Comment: The voltage at non inverting terminal of A2 with respect to ground is \$k(V_i \times V_{err})*R_{CS} - R_{sense} * I\$, Where \$I\$ is the current marked by the arrow going right to left from the ground symbol towards \$R_{sense}\$. This voltage determines when the transistor turns OFF. The peak inductor current occurs at transistor turn OFF.

Comment: Consider editing the question to include the *full* diagram with better cropping as well as values of the components (if available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Expression for V sense

\$V_{sense} = -1 \cdot I_{inductor} \cdot R_{sense}\$

where \$V_{sense}\$ is the voltage of the node immediately to the left of \$R_{sense}\$ and \$I_{inductor}\$ is the current flowing right to left from the ground symbol towards \$R_{sense}\$. The diagram is incomplete, but, the current \$I_{inductor}\$ is coming from the inductor through the MOSFET and is returning to the AC source \$V_{in}\$ to complete the circuit. The negative sign is to show that the voltage on the left side of \$R_{sense}\$ is *below* the voltage of the ground symbol since current is flowing right to left.

### RCS and peak inductor current

The current through the inductor would be steadily increasing while MOSFET is ON and reaches the peak at the instant MOSFET turns OFF. The output voltage of A2 controls when the MOSFET turns OFF. The expression for non inverting input of A2 is

\$k(\dots) R_{CS} - I_{inductor} \cdot R_{sense} \$.

i.e,

\$I_{inductor} = I_{setpoint}\frac{R_{CS}}{R_{sense}}\$ if the switch over point is approximated as the instant when non inverting input of A2 reaches zero volts. This is confirmed by the sentence you have quoted : "*For instance, suppose the the multiplier delivers 300 uA and RCS equals 2 kohm; then the maximum voltage across Rsense reaches 600 mV*".

Comment: Well explained, thanks

Comment: So Ri here, is just for biasing  A2,

Comment: It is not clear to me, but \$R_i, R_z, C_p, C_z\$, may be keeping A2 in linear operating region with some gain as well as doing some type of (low pass) filtering. Additionally, I assume that current through \$R_i\$ is small enough not to affect voltage across \$R_{sense}\$.